# Mediaplayer stretch video on WinRT

Tags: c#, video, windows-store-apps

I'm using the `<PlayerFramework:MediaPlayer>` in Xaml to display video in my Windows Store App. When the video is high resolution it uses full screen nicely. But when I open a video with low resolution it shows me just a little image centered on screen.

I tried `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` and `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"` but it does nothing. By the way it should stretch to full screen without using the aspect ratio.

How can I stretch the video to full screen size without keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: Try changing the `Stretch` property. There is also a `CycleDisplayMode` function which cycles through the different stretch modes.

Comment: Sorry but i cant find any of this. The only thing where i find something with stretch, are the properties for the alignment where i can set stretch as value. And some display mode is not available.

Comment: So a couple of quick questions: You are using C# (and Xaml) in a Windows Store app. What version of Windows Store apps? 8? 8.1? Further, what version of the `PlayerFramework` are you using? From what I can tell from the source, the Stretch property is only available in Windows 8.1 and Silverlight. I may be reading the Source wrong. Also, I am only reading the current version, so this may have changed. Further, make sure that it's being put into a panel that gives it enough space to stretch. Could you post your xaml? Controls like `StackPanel` are bad about this.